# Term for letters that appear as multiple different letters

Tags: writing-style, writing, letter-writing, handwriting

Is there a name for a letter or word that appears as multiple different letters/words. The best way I know of to explain what I am looking for is the comical true/false word ambiguity displayed below.

[image]

The picture above gives the appearance of both the word true and false. Is there a term for this word/letter ambiguity?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a type of **ambigram**, specifically a "perceptual shift" or "oscillation" ambigram. This term is used on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram#Types) and also on some other websites, such as "[A Through Approach to the Ambigram Along With Spectacular Examples](http://www.webgranth.com/a-through-approach-to-the-ambigram-along-with-spectacular-examples)" and "[Liquisearch](http://www.liquisearch.com/ambigram/ambigram_types)."